# htaccess - Rewrite any URI to find a php file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

All of the `.htaccess` file examples that I've seen are specific to a special page, but is there a better way with a PHP site to rewrite URLs for a static PHP website.

Let's assume assume the directory structure is as follows:

```
|--- index.php
|--- contact.php
|---/products/
|       |--- index.php
|       |--- features.php
|       |--- price.php
```

Is there a way to write the `.htaccess` that if the user goes to `example.com/contact/` or `example.com/products/` or `example.com/features/` the server will find the write page without having to specify every single page as they get added? Does this have be to handled in PHP?

Comment: I would think this would be a relatively standard approach. Nobody expects URLs with PHP on the end of them anymore.  Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475355/multiple-query-parameter-restful-url-with-htaccess

Comment: Of course, I totally agree!!! Trying to account for a potential issue with a project that I'm not coding but is built without a framework to automatically produce the URLs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey in that example given, what parsing code would you write, any examples? Sorry totally newbie at URL management, I've simply used frameworks and let them do the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use that in your root .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks for the reminder, I hate the 4 minute delay cause then I forget to come back later.

Comment: It gives us the opportunity to see if we have forgotten nothing ;-)